# How to separate key and value of each object inside array of objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects with the following format

```
var obj = [{
  "a": 1
}, {
  "b": 2
}, {
  "c": 3
}];
```

Would want to fetch keys and values out of each object separately inside this array of objects into a new array

Something like this:
`[{"key:"a","val:"1"],{"key":"b","val":"2"},{"key": "c","val":"3"]}`

Have tried the following but it is not working :

```js
var obj = [{
  "a": 1
}, {
  "b": 2
}, {
  "c": 3
}];

const result = obj.map(value => Object.keys(value)[0]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you expand this solution to show [
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
],[1,2,3] as output ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your current function you're returning just the key, not an object with key and value inside.
So following your logic, you just need to add a return that returns an object, which inside have the `Object.key` and `Object.value`.

See below, is that what you are looking for?

```js
var arrayObj = [
  {
    "a": 1
  }, 
  {
    "b": 2
  }, 
  {
    "c": 3
  }
];

const result = arrayObj.map((obj) => {  
  return {
      key: Object.keys(obj)[0], 
      val: Object.values(obj)[0]
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

There's also a possibility yo use `Object.entries(obj)[0]`, as you can see in *Anjaneyulu Batta* answer.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant but OP's example has `"val:"1"` - so the number is turned to a string. Just mentioning it - it might have been a typo in the question or otherwise unimportant.

Comment: that's true, I'll wait if he says something, if necessary I'll adjust to return a string

Answer (score 4):

We have to use `Object.keys` property to achieve it. Try below code

```js
var obj = [{
  "a": 1,
}, {
  "b": 2
}, {
  "c": 3
}];

const result = obj.map(value => {
  let [key, val] = Object.entries(value)[0];
  return {key, val}
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You could do `const [key, val] = Object.entries(value)[0];` and get both of them in one go

Comment: @adiga thanks! for letting me know. I will update it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to convert the array of objects to an array of entries. Then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each entry to an object:

```js
const arrayObj = [{ "a": 1 }, { "b": 2 }, { "c": 3 }];

const result = arrayObj
  .flatMap(Object.entries) // convert to an array of entries
  .map(([key, val]) => ({ key, val })); // convert each entry to an object

console.log(result);
```